# Why can't `mongoimport` connect to my free-tier MongoDB Atlas cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I have a free-tier MongoDB Atlas cluster, and I want to upload some JSON to it from my Mac.

I tried to run this:

```sh
mongoimport -h cluster0-shard-00-00-cxacx.mongodb.net:27017 -d literature -c books -u xxxx -p xxxx --file ~/Desktop/books.json --type json --ssl
```

However, I got this error:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers, openssl error: SSL errors: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I tried without `--ssl` in the command, and I got this instead:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Why can't it reach the server?

More info:

- My `mongoimport` version is `r3.2.22`.
- My OS is macOS `10.14.5`.
- My cluster version is `4.0.10`.
- The user has admin permission.
- My IP address is white-listed.
- I can connect to the cluster with the MongoDB Node Driver.
- I get the same problem with `mongofiles`.
- I also tried variations of the command with no success that included `--authenticationDatabase admin` and the name of the replica set and other server nodes.

**Update:** I was able to upload the JSON file by sending it to a Linux cloud server and running `mongoimport` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Monogo atlas gives you service records (SRV) and not host.
"cluster0-shard-00-00-cxacx.mongodb.net" It is not a proper host.

Use it like:

> mongoimport --uri
>   "mongodb://root:@atlas-host1:27017,atlas-host2:27017,atlas-host3:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=myAtlasRS&authSource=admin"
>   -d literature -c books -file ~/Desktop/books.json --type json --ssl

You will get complete URI from mongo atlas connect screen

Comment: It looks like the latest Mac version of `mongoimport` does not accept the `uri` option. When I run your command, it gives me this message: `error parsing command line options: unknown option "uri"`

Comment: `mongoimport --uri "mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@cluster0-shard-00-00-cxacx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-cxacx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-cxacx.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin" -d literature -c books -file ~/Desktop/books.json --type json --ssl`

Comment: You need to remove database option (-d literature) and it to uri "...:27017/literature?ssl..."

Comment: I just tried it, but I still get the error about the `unknown option "uri"`.

Comment: Seems to be some other issue. I'm also on mac with the latest mongo installed. And it works for me.